# Lower Caret Symbol

Tags: symbols

What is the code for creating the caret-like symbol as in the following image?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `\wedge`?

Comment: Ah, that could work, but I'd prefer a smaller wedge as in the image, if possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick hack:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\smallwedge}{%
  \mathbin{\mathchoice
    {\scriptstyle\wedge}
    {\scriptstyle\wedge}
    {\scriptscriptstyle\wedge}
    {\scriptscriptstyle\wedge}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\smallerwedge}{\mathbin{\scriptscriptstyle\wedge}}

\begin{document}
$0\wedge 0_{0\wedge 0}$

$0\smallwedge 0_{0\smallwedge 0}$

$0\smallerwedge 0$
\end{document}
```

You can use `\smallwedge` also in first level subscripts/superscripts (it won't be smaller in second level ones).

For `\smallerwedge` only the main size can do. If you don't need it in sub/superscripts it might be the simplest solution.

[image]

A different approach might be scaling the wedge symbol (but using the boldface version, so it wouldn't be too thin):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\newcommand{\smallwedge}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\scalebox{.5}{\boldmath$\wedge$}}}%
}

\begin{document}
$0\smallwedge 0_{0\smallwedge 0}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is more expensive in terms of efficiency, but has the advantage of working at any level.

Comment: @KermittheHermit I added another solution

Answer (score 3):

Because the word LaTeX wasn't mentioned in the question, I would show the plainTeX solution (which works in LaTeX too).

```
\newfam\swedgefam   \newcount\tmpnum
\font\tmpT=cmbsy10 scaled500 \font\tmpS=cmbsy7 scaled500 \font\tmpSS=cmbsy5 scaled500
\textfont\swedgefam=\tmpT \scriptfont\swedgefam=\tmpS \scriptscriptfont\swedgefam=\tmpSS
\tmpnum=\swedgefam \multiply\tmpnum by256 \advance\tmpnum by"205E % binop + code
\mathchardef\smallwedge=\tmpnum

$0\smallwedge0_{0\smallwedge0_{0\smallwedge0}}$
```

The advantages of this solution:

- It is efficient: there is no typesetting of each `\smallwedge` in four branches, no `\scalebox` in each branch.
- It works in all common formats: plain TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt.
- It is educational example how to add new math symbol from selected font in plain TeX.

The disadvantage of this solution:

- The new math family is allocated only for one math symbol. Classical TeX (and eTeX) have only 16 such families available (and four of them are always allocated). So this seems to be as big wasting resources.